# Chrome DevTools Protocol: available domains per target type?

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol

What is the best way to determine which CDP domains are available for a specific Target type? For example, `Network` domain is not available in the `browser` targets, but can be used in `page` sessions.

[Getting started with CDP](https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md) provides a link to chromium source, but that seems outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: there is no reliable way that I know of other than checking sources

---

Some background: I am the author of [chrome-devtools-kotlin](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/chrome-devtools-kotlin), a Kotlin client for the CDP, and I faced the exact same issue when trying to provide a type-safe API that respected the target domains available to each target types.

There is technically a [Schema domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Schema/) that allows to list domains and is supported by the `Page`, `ServiceWorker`, and `SharedWorker` target types (AFAICT), but it's deprecated now, so I'm not sure we can really rely on it.

Eventually, I didn't find a better way than looking at the Chromium sources, and this is extremely brittle. The current query I run is the following:
https://source.chromium.org/search?q=%22session-%3ECreateAndAddHandler%22%20f:devtools&ss=chromium

Every few months or so, I go check the Chromium sources again and check the domains, and then update my own [target_types.json](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/chrome-devtools-kotlin/blob/main/protocol/target_types.json) which is one of my inputs for codegen. If I manage to understand how to use the chrome search API, I might automate this tedious process someday but it will still be inherently brittle (no matter how convenient I can make it).

I also have a test that runs a `zenika/alpine-chrome:latest` Docker container, and then accesses the deprecated `schema` domain to check if the server supports some domains that my library doesn't list as supported. But one day the schema domain may be entirely removed, so I need to change strategies. Another option for this test would be to use the `/json/protocol` HTTP API instead, but I'm not sure it discriminates target types.